# Как добавить точки на карту с разными символами через renderer класса FeatureLayer?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, typescript, arcgis

Как добавить точки на карту с разными символами через renderer класса FeatureLayer? Версия arcgis/core - 4.22.2

Cталкивался ли кто-то с подобной потребностью?
Если да - то прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Однозначного решения не нашёл - поэтому использовал несколько Feature Layer - и туда прокидывал иконки через PictureMarkerSymbol.

Есть ещё вариант через:

```
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/uniquevaluerenderer-amd.html#uniquevaluerenderer
```